# Snowflake run multiple MERGE statements on same table

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a very large table (4+ billion rows) structured  as follows :

```
user_id    month    nb_logins
-----------------------------
1          01       0
1          02       1
1          03       4
1          04       0
...        ...      ...
2          01       5
2          02       0
2          03       0
2          04       1
```

I would like to add a new column which is simply the cumulative sum of `nb_logins` partitioned by `user_id` and ordered by `month`.

I used to compute the whole thing in one query, however I decided to parallelize this as each user is independant (i.e. I can compute the cumsum for user 1 and user 2 in parallel).

Now, to parallelize I've create a list of "partitions" based on `user_id` (it's an evenly balanced int), let's say I have the following two partitions :

1. `user_id between 0 and 10`
2. `user_id between 11 and 20`

So I run two `MERGE` requests in parallel, one for each partition, however I see that most of the requests are `BLOCKED` in Snowflake because they try to write onto the same micro-partition.

Question : what would be the best way to parallelize this operation ?

Comment: when you say partitioned by `user_id` and ordered by `month`, what exactly do you mean by that?  Are you loading the table ordered by `user_id, month`?

Comment: as a note, the reason this is blocked is most likely because partitioning on Snowflake micropartitions isn't absolute.  You likely have at least 1 micropartition that contains multiple values for user_id, which creates a partition lock for whichever statement gets there first.  You may actually be better off keeping this statement as a single statement and making your warehouse larger to process more of the statement in a single pass.

Comment: no I meant partitioned by and order by in a "window function" way, meaning this is parallelizable. and yes I've resized the warehouse though I still want to find a way to parallelize this operation. as of today I store the values in `temporary tables` and then merge the union of them all.

Comment: You are going to get a lock trying to do multiple MERGE statements against a single table.  Not really a way around that.  You might want to consider physically separating your table into multiple tables, and then put a view over the union of the tables.  If you are already partitioned by user_id, then I assume that queries are typically filtered by that already.  In which case, Snowflake will know to only hit the necessary tables of the UNION ALL in order to provide a result.